# Creating a Map with a Floating Number as Zoom Level Using Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am creating a map using mapbox.js using the code below

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map_canvas',null,{
    centre: [4.113028, 30.392318],      
    'minZoom':6,
    'maxZoom': 8,
    'zoomSnap':1,
    'zoomDelta':1,
    maxBounds: bounds
})
.setView([7.8, 28.7],6);
```

This displays the intended map including the base layer(openstreetmap) however the zoom level is higher than intended but when i change zoom 6 the map becomes congested. I have changed the code to the one below. Now i get the perfect zoom level but the base layer does not display.

Second code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map_canvas',null,{
centre: [4.113028, 30.392318],      
'minZoom':6,
'maxZoom': 8,
'zoomSnap':0.5,
'zoomDelta':0.5,
maxBounds: bounds
  }).setView([7.8, 28.7],6.5);
```

Why does the base layer disappear when i use a float number as zoom level? 
Thanks

Comment: What versions of mapbox-gl and leaflet? Fractional zoom arrived in Leaflet 1.x and Mapbox took a while to support it. See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet/issues/59

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated mapbox.js to v3.1.1 and it has worked.